# PHP page load seems to be requesting itself and misinterpreting the result

Tags: php, http, httpwebrequest, mime

I'm working on a messy PHP page by another developer and I was analyzing the resource view in the Webkit developer tools and noticed that the page (index.php) **makes an HTTP requests for itself and then interprets the results as an image** despite it being sent with the text/html header. Because of this it throws the warning:

> Resource interpreted as image but transferred with MIME type text/html.

Looking at the time graph the call comes after the `<head>` because it has already requested images for the body. Sometimes there are even two 'bad' requests.

Can anyone explain what might be happening and/or suggest how to fix this?
Could these be related to PHP includes?

Comment: Taking out the includes makes the requests disappear. Still, why does it show up as requests to itself and why are those requests interpreted as images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how Webkit is making requests, but the only time I've seen this kind of behavior (a script calling itself as an image) is when:

- Image URLs are supposed to be generated and are not - leaving the image source as `''` or this current URL.
- A `mod_rewrite` is too 'greedy', and redirects image requests - including the browser's favicon request - to the bootstrap (or similar) script.

Does Webkit request a favicon? That would be a later request in the timeline.

Comment: I think the first one is pretty likely. A bit more on it here: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#emptysrc